# why html5 feature not working in my android application?

Tags: android, html

I want to work with html file, I did it when I deploy it, it won't workout  (The input html page need to be shown but it shows webpage not available when I deploy ) ! Error msg also not in LOG !Any help please. Where is the wrong I'm doing ?

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView webView =null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android-assets/www/index.html");

    }
}
```

Here my javascript.

```
function sayhello(){
alert("hi", document.getElementById('name'),value);
}
```

and html file is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
What is ur name  ?
<input id="name" value="">
<button onclick="sayhello()">say hello</button>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

and the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "it won't workout" what does that exactly mean? App not starting, app showing blank screen, app crashing, phone exploding?

Comment: The html page should come, but it is not coming...Why and where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
file:///android-asset/www/index.html
```

Just get rid of the 's'

**UPDATE:**

You can also load pages with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Where the second param is your page to load.

Comment: still not working. assets is the inbuilt folder and why it should be "asset". Or is there any plugins I need to provide to work with html5.

Comment: I can't find an article on an official channel, but i have used android_asset and it works. I've updated my answer with another method which you can try.